# rs0:FATAL error after recreating the deleted Previous Primary Member in 3 Machine cluster created using VMWare

Tags: mongodb

In my project MongoDb is installed in our software.I created 3 Machines in cloud Using VMWare. Regarding my testbed I can say that, I have ESXI software installed in cisco UCS-Blade and above that,we are creating our VM Machines with our created software(MongoDB 2.4.6 is already pre-installed in our software).

For checking cluster creation,I created 3 VM Machines and created cluster among themselves.I created a database and put some data in primary and its successfully reflecting in other Machines.

Then to check replication,I switched off the primary VM and other machine from secondary become primary as excepted.

But when I created the machine by using the same ip(The IP of the Machine which I deleted Previously),in mongodb its giving rs0):FATAL error.It is not going to secondary VM as excepted.

If I type rs.status() in that machine its always telling its in syncing state.
Request you to kindly help on this regard or if its a known bug,pls give me the bug ID.

Comment: You are really on the wrong site. Stackoverflow is for programming based topics. You should be submitting on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) which is better suited to your question.

Comment: The MongoDB logs will have a reason why this node has gone into FATAL. In order for someone to provide an answer as to why this happened you must provide the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Got my Answer from Outside Source.So thought of knowledge sharing for others to follow.

A MongoDB node can come up in FATAL state (not joining back its cluster) if a database content is too much out-of-sync.
You can find the current node status by running the mongo shell with command ‘mongo’ – the status is in the shell prompt. You can exit the shell using “exit”.
To recover from this situation manually, do the following:

1)  On the ‘FATAL’ node, run mongo shell with the command ‘mongo’;
2)  In the mongo shell, list all local databases using “show dbs”;
3)  For each database present, do “use ” and “db.dropDatabase()”;
4)  After all databases are gone, do “use admin” and “db.shutdownServer()”;
5)  Upstart will restart mongo server automatically and it will now join the cluster and sync.